# How to - CSS background for border right

Tags: css, css-float

I'm having problems setting an image as the right hand border to #left in the example below.  Currently the border appears but it is about 200px to the right, rather than 500px to the right.

Any idea what's going wrong please?

Thanks!

```
<html>
<STYLE type="text/css">

#wrapper, #left, #right, .sub_box
{ border: 1px solid black; }

.sub_box
{ float:left; }

#left
{ background: url("dots.gif") right repeat-y; }
</STYLE>

<div id="wrapper" style="width:882px">

<div id="left" style="width:500px;float:left">
    <div class="sub_box" style="width:200px">
    <p>sub box</p>
            </div>
    <div class="sub_box" style="width:200px">
            <p>sub box</p>        
            </div>
    <div class="sub_box" style="width:200px">
    <p>sub box</p>
            </div>
</div>

<div id="right" style="width:200px;float:right">    
    <p>Right column here</p>
    </div>

</div>   
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you miss «top»? background: url("dots.gif") right top repeat-y;

Comment: @rix try my answer i think that will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies but try the code.  It does not work!!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem. Can you check this fiddle(  http://jsfiddle.net/hKwbY/ )and tell me which browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
background: url("dots.gif") 500px 0px repeat-y;
```

Or adjust, as you want.

Comment: agreed this should work.  Only when i use position: right do i see the border.  using the x,y coordinates does not seem to work..?

Comment: @rix try to decrease its position from right, user 490px or 498px as fit you requirement...

Comment: The answer to this is use background-size.  Using that i got it to work.  Try your answer with my code you will see it does not work.

Comment: @rix actually it is working in ie6 ie7 and chrome also. I have used your code to do that..